# Importing OptaPlanner-Core.jar into the drools workbench

Tags: drools, optaplanner, kie-workbench

I am trying to write some business rules for use with OptaPlanner from the drools workbench.  In order to do so, I need to add the optaplanner-core.jar file as a dependency so my rules files will validate and build.  When uploading the jar file, I get this exception:

```
May 14, 2015 2:41:28 PM org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.BuildServiceImpl build
SEVERE: org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedderException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.optaplanner:optaplanner-core:jar:6.1.0.Final
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedderException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.optaplanner:optaplanner-core:jar:6.1.0.Final
        at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:44)
        at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:35)
        at org.kie.scanner.ArtifactResolver.getResolverFor(ArtifactResolver.java:100)
        at org.kie.scanner.KieModuleMetaDataImpl.<init>(KieModuleMetaDataImpl.java:68)
        at org.kie.scanner.KieModuleMetaData$Factory.newKieModuleMetaData(KieModuleMetaData.java:30)
        at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.Builder.build(Builder.java:177)
        at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.BuildServiceImpl.doBuild(BuildServiceImpl.java:153)
        at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.BuildServiceImpl.build(BuildServiceImpl.java:79)
        at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.BuildServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.build(BuildServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
        at org.guvnor.common.services.builder.ResourceChangeIncrementalBuilder$3.execute(ResourceChangeIncrementalBuilder.java:236)
        at org.guvnor.common.services.builder.IncrementalBuilderExecutorManager$1.run(IncrementalBuilderExecutorManager.java:50)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedderException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.optaplanner:optaplanner-core:jar:6.1.0.Final
        at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedder.readProject(MavenEmbedder.java:298)
        at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:42)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.optaplanner:optaplanner-core:jar:6.1.0.Final
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:384)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:525)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:509)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:202)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:114)
        at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedder.readProject(MavenEmbedder.java:294)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Failure to transfer org.optaplanner:optaplanner:pom:6.1.0.Final from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.optaplanner:optaplanner:pom:6.1.0.Final from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:203)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:903)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:755)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:375)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.optaplanner:optaplanner:pom:6.1.0.Final from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.optaplanner:optaplanner:pom:6.1.0.Final from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:150)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.optaplanner:optaplanner:pom:6.1.0.Final from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.optaplanner:optaplanner:pom:6.1.0.Final from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        ... 35 more
```

I tried by uploading the file as well as just using the Add button and specifying the Maven Repo information, I get the same exception.  Any ideas why I am unable to upload this jar file and what I might need to do?  Thanks!